# What is the physical meaning of complex jacobian?

Tags: complex-geometry, jacobian

The Jacobian matrix means about the physical deformation due to change of coordinates. But the Jacobian matrix with complex values may be implies that the space is complex, but the physical deformation is going to be real. So, how can a real space have a complex deformation? If the complex deformation values are plausible, then what would be the physical meaning of these values?

Comment: Why do you say the physical deformation (given by complex-valued functions) should be real? Where did "real space" come from?

Comment: Deformations are on a materials which are physically realizable. How can the deformations on them be complex?

Comment: You are not asking a mathematics question here. If the physical deformation is real, then I don't see how you arrive at complex functions whose derivatives go into the Jacobian. You're the one presenting us with those complex functions, so the question is for you to answer.

Comment: Agreed. For the Jacobian to be complex, the physical space has to be complex. Now, what are the per-requisites to call the space of a physically realizable material (PRM) to be a complex. One of the condition is that, the metric space is real. Second is that, eigenvalues are real. What else could be the condition to be satisfied for a complex space that represent a PRM?

Note: I'm not shifting my goalpost or question. I'm just trying to expand my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The Jacobian is the derminant of the partial derivatives. It can't be complex if the functions and coordinates are all real.

Comment: True. Agreed. But my question is not on that. I just want the physical meaning of the complex terms in a Jacobian.